# Python script stops responding when receiving saved messages

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am writing a script to download all of my saved messages from telegram using Telethon library to interact with Telegram's API.

But as soon as any method from the library gets called, the script gets stuck in some kind of a loop or is waiting for some response.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Here is a snippet of a code I run:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

api_id = 12345678
api_hash = '' #hash value

client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

async def main():
    saved = open('saved_messages.txt', 'a')
    me = await client.get_me()
    async for message in client.get_messages('me'):
        saved.write(f'{message.text}\n')
        print(message.id, message.text)
    saved.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

All the code is from the [quick-start](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html).

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

I tried looking up the problem to see if anyone had already faced it but found nothing.

Comment: Have you checked if it's receiving any messages in `me`? It will get stuck in that `await` until it receives something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues, to begin:

```
async for message in client.get_messages('me'):
```

Isn't valid. You'll need to `await` `client.get_messages`, so make it:

```py
me = await client.get_me()
messages = await client.get_messages('me', limit=100)
for message in messages:
    ....
```

**Note** the `limit=100`, otherwise you'll just receive the latest saved message

---

As second, you'll need to use the event_loop from asyncio:

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This way I get a `saved_messages.txt` with the expected content.

---

Full code:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

saved = open('saved_messages.txt', 'a')

client = TelegramClient('anon', '1', '2')
client.start()

async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    messages = await client.get_messages('me', limit=100)
    for message in messages:
        saved.write(f'{message.text}\n')
        print(message.id, message.text)
    saved.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issues, it helped. Could you please explain why do I have to use event_loop instead of asyncio.run(). I thought the latest was preferable, though it didn't work in my case.